# How to add up values of checkboxes in real time using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Should be easy, but this code isn't working for me:

```
$("#checkboxdiv input:checkbox").change(function() {
            var total = 0;
            $('#checkboxdiv input:checkbox:checked').each(function() {
                total += parseInt(this.value, 10);
            });
            $('#totalsdiv').text(total);
        });
```

The checkboxes to consider are all in the #checkbox div, and I'm trying to fill in the div with the total amount.

Thanks.

Comment: So, what's not working?

Comment: It works for me : http://jsbin.com/asifob/1/edit

Comment: Works for me http://jsfiddle.net/Burnacid/RcUwc/

Comment: You mentioned all of the checkboxes are in the "#checkbox div". If this is the case, is your selector simply wrong? Instead of `#checkboxdiv` try `#checkbox`.

Comment: I apologize. It was indeed an unrelated error--a variable without the proper capitalization. Sigh...

Comment: @user371699 I don't know if you can delete your question (no good or upvoted answer). If you can't, the best will probably be to delete it or I'll make a CW answer. BTW thanks to have confirmed you made an error, that's better for people who have tried to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As the code is fine and works](http://jsbin.com/asifob/1/edit), it's probable there is an unrelated error elsewhere.

You should use the [developer tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/overview) to debug and hunt it.

Comment: Lost over 2 hours over a dumb mistake =\

Answer (score 0):

You could try to listen for the click event on the CheckBox, instead of the change event.

Comment: Given that OP's code is working (see fiddles), I don't think this answer will help.

Comment: I've had cross-browser problems in the past with this, it could be browser related, that's why I opted this answer.

Answer (score -2):

Without knowing your problem I'll guess at this

```
        $("#checkboxdiv input:checkbox").change(function() {
            var total = 0;
            $('#checkboxdiv input:checkbox:checked').each(function() {
                total += parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
            });
            $('#totalsdiv').text(total);
        });
```

Comment: Why use val instead of value ?